# Show the same image in cells of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I need to show the same image in cells of `UICollectionView` but with following logic:

- I have 14 different background images
- I need to repeat the same image for every cell which is multiple of 14.

eg:

```
indexPath.row == 1 ,   
indexPath.row == 14,   
indexPath.row == 28
```

and so on, put one image

```
indexPath.row == 2 ,   
indexPath.row == 15,   
indexPath.row == 29
```

set another image, and so on.

How is possible to fix this request ?

I already tried this code, but seems no success :(

```
- (void)setImageForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)curCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//=>    Get service image
UIImageView *imgService = (UIImageView *)[curCell viewWithTag:101];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    if (i == indexPath.row && indexPath.row % 13 == 0)
    {
        imgService.image        = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_%d" , i]];
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The solution is actually very simple. But shouldn't you try it out first and post a question if you encounter problems, instead of asking for someone to give you an answer?

Comment: Is your request about loading the images, or about picking the right one for the row?  If the latter, check out the modulo operator, %.  (indexPath.row % 14) will return the "remainder" after dividing by 14.  You can then use this as an index into an array of images.

Comment: @Rick: I updated code with what I've tried, but no success

Comment: what return value you put on -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView

Comment: @Bejibun: 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

Comment: Sorry I mean in this method -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: @Bejibun: - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.arrServices.count;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
if(indexPath.row < 14)
{
    imgService.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_%d" , indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
     if (indexPath.row % 14 == 0)
     {
         for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 14; i++)
         {
            imgService.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_%d" , i]];
         }
     }
}
```

or

```
imgService.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_%d" , indexPath.row % 14]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)setImageForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)curCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // I would prefer to subclass the cell instead of using tag
    UIImageView *imgService = (UIImageView *)[curCell viewWithTag:101];
    imgService.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"service_%d.png", indexPath.row % 14]];
}
```

(Note: I typed this outside of Xcode and I assumed that your images start with service_0.png. If not, do adjust accordingly.)

By the way,

```
indexPath.row == 0,  <-- should start with 0 instead of 1   
indexPath.row == 14,   
indexPath.row == 28 
...
indexPath.row == 1,   <-- should be 1
indexPath.row == 15,   
indexPath.row == 29
```